# Terminal Tips and Tricks for Mac OS X is missing

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have bookmarked, a couple of weeks ago, a top voted question having title **Terminal Tips and Tricks For Mac OS X** and question id **52483**.

Why was it deleted?

Answer (score 6):

It was locked because it was a list-type non-question with link-baiting merit with an SU focus.

List-types are discouraged and closed as off-topic or subjective/argumentative. Any new questions trying to replicate that behaviour will not live though.

But, it was created long ago and linked from a few places with honey dripping from its lips nonetheless.

Locking keeps it alive but does not allow any new content to be added into the mud of its mix.

It's now undeleted.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of the locked meaning but, why was it deleted?

Comment: This post is how a politician would answer a post. Or someone trying to give you a framework without trying to presume for someone else and helping you bide time. @sys

Comment: +1 for the genuineness :)

Answer (score 3):

The [question](https://superuser.com/questions/52483) was deleted on 2010-11-24 by [Diago](https://superuser.com/users/3981/diago)♦. It had [previously](https://superuser.com/posts/52483/revisions) been [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) (i.e., basically, made read-only — locking has nothing to do with closing) since 2010-08-05. (Only ♦moderators and ≥10k-rep users can see deleted questions.) I have no idea *why* the question was deleted. It can still be undeleted by a ♦moderator.

For the time being, the content is still available via the [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tkkEtimeTdsJ:superuser.com/questions/52483/terminal-tips-and-tricks-for-mac-os-x). When it goes, it will undoubtedly live on on one of the many sites that mirror SU (finally a use for them!). The question is in the [data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) produced before it was deleted.

Comment: @Gilles thanks, curious to know the reason :)

Comment: I'm guessing it was deleted because it was a "list" question but I don't think it was "bad" enough to delete. IIRC John Gruber had linked to it and though I don't use OS X - the tips were pretty neat.

Comment: OTOH, 10k+ should be able to nominate to undelete, right ?

Comment: @Sathya that was a golden post; it scares me that a Mod can decide to delete a question with that value, personally I hope it was just a mistake.

Comment: @Sathya: I don't see a way for me to vote to undelete. I gather from [Jon Seigel's post on SO Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62035/are-deleted-answers-automatically-removed-or-is-that-done-by-a-user-with-access/62043#62043) that this is because the question was locked, so only a ♦moderator can do anything to it.

Comment: @Gilles that link explains, thanks.